# scrollview insde flatlist not scrolling

Tags: javascript, react-native, scrollview, react-native-flatlist

i have this flatlist in render():

```
render() {
  return (
    <FlatList
      ref='listRef'
      data={this.props.data}
      renderItem={this.renderItem}
      keyExtractor={(item, index) => index.toString()}
    />   
  )
}
```

Then inside renderItem() i have:

```
return (            
  <View style={{flex:1}}>
    <ScrollView style={{flex:1}}> 
      {item.mascotas.map(function(d, index){
        return (
            <View key={index} style={{flex:1}}>
                <Image source={require('./img/base-face-image.png')} style={styles.mascotas_list_item_img} /> 
                <View style={styles.mascotas_list_item_details}>
                    <Text style={styles.mascotas_list_item_details_name}>{d.nombre}</Text>

                </View>
            </View>
          )
      })}                    
    </ScrollView>
  </View>
```

As you can see the parent view and its childs have flex:1, i've also tried adding flex:1 to FlatList but doesn't work neither. I need the scrollview to scroll.

Comment: remove `ScrollView` from the `renderItem()` then check....and also read the docs for the flalist [here](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/flatlist.html)

Comment: @KishanGujarati that didn't work...

Comment: you can use `ListView` instead of `FlatList`

Comment: ListView is deprecated

Comment: Did you check https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/1966#issuecomment-285130701? It's a solution for a ScrollView that has ListView in it, but you could use it as an idea for your case...